# Limiting the network bandwidth in java

Tags: java, bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

I need to do following things:

`1. Find the current network bandwidth.`

`2. Limit the bandwidth to download the file by 50%.`

I did some research over this but i am not able to find any good way of doing this.

Like calculating the bandwidth by sending some data for some time and doing some arithmetic over it.

I was wondering if there is any better approach? Since this will take extra time(sending and receiving data+calculating bandwidth).
Every time a download request comes i don't want to do it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch a quantum of data.  Remember how long it takes.
Sleep for the same amount of time.

Note that this isn't guaranteed to work for sufficiently small quanta, since
the system's read-ahead will be working to keep the input flowing even when you're
not asking for it.